# Text selection and replacement not working properly in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, text, replace, textarea

I'm trying to make buttons for formatting (like making bold, italic etc) the selected text (md and/or html) of `textarea` tag using JavaScript.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't without giving any error.

**Code link**
https://jsfiddle.net/3gn75zLb

**JS Code**

```
function formatText(style) {
    var textarea_editor = document.getElementById('md-code');

    //get Selection
    var index_start = textarea_editor.selectionStart;
    var index_end = textarea_editor.selectionEnd;
    var text = textarea_editor.value;
    var selectedText = text.substring(index_start, index_end);
    var formatedText = selectedText;

    
        //format
        switch(style.toLowerCase()) {
            case 'b':
                var formatedText = "**"+selectedText+"**";
                break;

            case 'i':
                var formatedText = "*"+selectedText+"*";
                break;

            case 'u':
                var formatedText = "<u>"+selectedText+"</u>";
                break;

            case 'sup':
                var formatedText = "<sup>"+selectedText+"</sup>";
                break;

            case 'sub':
                var formatedText = "<sub>"+selectedText+"</sub>";
                break;

            case 'img':
                var formatedText = "![]("+selectedText+")";
                break;

            default:
                var formatedText = selectedText;
                break;
        }

        textarea_editor.innerHTML = text.substring(0, index_start)+formatedText+text.substring(index_end, text.length);
    }
```

There are click events associated with buttons to call the `formatText()` function

Like

> formatText('b') to enclose the selected text with `**` to make it bold in markdown.

**Questions**

- Is there any problem with the code?
- Is there any better/easy way to do this using jQuery or anything else?

Comment: Post your code using the code snippet feature. It would be easier to debug.

Comment: Som Shekhar Mukherjee! I've added jsfiddle link to the html & JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the `innerHTML` of the `textarea`, you need to set `value` property of the text area.

`innerHTML` with text area can only be used to set the initial content of the text area but as soon as you type something in the `textarea`, `innerHTML` won't do anything, you need to then use the `value` property.

Also, currently if no text is selected even then the code adds styles, you can simply return from the function if the `selectedText` is empty.

See the code below:

```js
function formatText(style) {
  var textarea_editor = document.getElementById('md-code');
  
  //get Selection
  var index_start = textarea_editor.selectionStart;
  var index_end = textarea_editor.selectionEnd;
  var text = textarea_editor.value;
  var selectedText = text.substring(index_start, index_end);
  var formatedText = selectedText;
  
  if (!selectedText) return;
  
  //format
  switch (style.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'b':
      var formatedText = "**" + selectedText + "**";
      break;

    case 'i':
      var formatedText = "*" + selectedText + "*";
      break;

    case 'u':
      var formatedText = "<u>" + selectedText + "</u>";
      break;

    case 'sup':
      var formatedText = "<sup>" + selectedText + "</sup>";
      break;

    case 'sub':
      var formatedText = "<sub>" + selectedText + "</sub>";
      break;

    case 'img':
      var formatedText = "![](" + selectedText + ")";
      break;

    default:
      var formatedText = selectedText;
      break;
  }

  textarea_editor.value = text.substring(0, index_start) + formatedText + text.substring(index_end, text.length);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron bg-white px-2 py-0 m-0">
  <div class="my-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formatText('b')"><b>B</b></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formatText('i')"><i>I</i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formatText('u')"><u>U</u></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formatText('sup')">T<sup>abc</sup></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formatText('sub')">T<sub>abc</sub></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="formatText('img')">Img</button>
  </div>
  <textarea id="md-code" class="form-control" rows="20" name="note_content" placeholder="Markdown and/or HTML text"></textarea>
</div>
```